# Getting fetch returns more than requested number of rows error

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I need to enter data into a table called transaction, but validate it before insert. For instance, I need to check if customerno exists in customer table, if it doesn't exist raise an error. 
Then when I've validated all data I need to get data the from transaction table and enter it into order and orderspecs table. Im not sure if I need a where in the select when I'm selecting all the customer numbers into the variable customerids. This is the code I've used for the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger transaction_trigger
before insert
on transactions
for each row
declare
    customerids number;
    employeeids number;
    inventoryids number;
begin
    select cno into customerids from customers;
    select employeeno into employeeids from employees;
    select itemno into inventoryids from inventory;

    if :NEW.cno not in (customerids) then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'customer does not exist in customer table');
    elsif :NEW.employeeno not in (employeeids) then 
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'employee does not exist in employee table');
    elsif :NEW.itemno1 not in (inventoryids) then 
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'inventory item 1 does not exist in inventory table'); 
    elsif :NEW.itemno2 not in (inventoryids) then 
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'inventory item 2 does not exist in inventory table');
    else
        insert into orders 
        values (:NEW.orderno, :NEW.cno, :NEW.employeeno, :NEW.received, :NEW.shipped);

        insert into orderspecs 
        values (:NEW.orderno, :NEW.itemno1, :NEW.quantity1);

        insert into orderspecs 
        values (:NEW.orderno, :NEW.itemno2, :NEW.quantity2);

        update inventory 
        set qty_on_hand = :NEW.quantity1 + :NEW.quantity2 + :NEW.quantity3
        where itemno = :NEW.itemno1 OR itemno = :NEW.itemno2 OR itemno = :NEW.itemno3;
    end if;
end;
```

But when I run my function that will be doing the insert into the transaction table using this trigger to validate and insert into order and orderspecs table I'm getting this error:

```
Error code:-1422. Error Message: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.TRANSACTION_TRIGGER", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.TRANSACTION_TRIGGER'
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: What is confusing?  Your code starts with three `select`s that all look like they return more than one row.

Comment: You should use foreign keys for enforcing relational integrity. Not only do triggers not scale well they do not work in multi-user environments. This approach would **inevitably** lead to data corruption in a real life application.

Comment: Was already thinking of my response when I read @APC.  This is _NOT_ a good use of triggers.  Aside from the reported problem and solution, and aside from simply allowing properly defined FK and constraints to do the enforcement, this type of processing should be done in the application procedure, not in a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code:

```
declare
customerids number;
employeeids number;
inventoryids number;
begin
    select cno into customerids from customers;
    select employeeno into employeeids from employees;
    select itemno into inventoryids from inventory;
```

You can 't affect a multi-line  resultset of a query to a number like that.

For your purpose, , I think that a couple of `exists` queries would get he job done:

```
begin
    if not exists (select 1 from customers where cno = :NEW.cno) then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'customer does not exist in customer table');
    elsif not exists (select 1 from employees where employeeno = :NEW.employeeno)then 
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'employee does not exist in employee table');
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to start with something like this:

```
select count(*) into num_customers
from customers
where cno = :new.cno;

select count(*) into num_employees
from employees
where employeeno = :new.employeeno;

select count(*) into num_inventory
from inventory
where itemno = :new.itemno;
```

You can then test whether or not the counts are `0`.

That said, all this better handled via `foreign key` constraints rather than triggers.  A properly declared data model would not need this checks in a trigger.